# LibreOffice Impress goes grey when I save the file

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice

I use LibreOffice Impress to edit a pptx (Microsoft Powerpoint) file. Whenever I save the file or edit on the slide, the screen turns grey and the CPU usage shoots to 100% (with soffice.bin). I have to wait for a while before it comes back.

Can anyone suggest any workaround or settings to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.1 and LibreOffice 5.1.4.2.

PS: if I save the format as odp, it seems there is no such greyout issue.

Comment: Have you tried [WPS Office](http://wps.com/)?  It's free, and seems really compatible with MS Office files.  Presentation is used for PowerPoint files.

Comment: Odd. Is it a particularly large file?

Comment: @Nick It is a small file less than 2MB. I will use odp format then covert back to pptx later.